# How to overcome issues with logs?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When I goto "Monitor" page for a function, there is a "Logs" panel. Two issues here

1. The scrollbar doesn't function - what's with that?
2. The log is incomplete. Sometimes it'll start mid-word with ".." in front. Why is that?

How can I get the full log? Where is this stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chris from the Functions team here

Our built in Monitoring has a few rough edges that have lasted longer than they should have. To address your specific issues:

1. We'll have pagination and date filtering next month. You can work around this today by going to your Kudu site (Function App Settings > Go To Kudu) and then under the tools menu, go to the "Web jobs dashbaord" and then clicking on the "Functions" option at the top right. (or .scm.azurewebsites.net/AzureJobs).
2. The "..." thing is a truncation issue which will be fixed in our next release, which should land later this month. [GitHub #1051](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/pull/1051)

Once those are solved, you shouldn't have issues getting the full log.

Where it is stored is in your Storage Account, but when you're using the portal (or you set the [fileLoggingMode option in your host.json to always](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json), we log to disk. There's just perf/cost issues there, so we don't do it always. It's accessible, as @4c74356b41 said at

```
 home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\[Host|Functions\{functionname}]
```

We are working on adding Application Insights integration in the near future which I'd recommend folks look into. We'll have the option of having your traces uploaded there instead. It has a great experience for alerting on those logs/etc. You can do this today if you bring in the App Insights SDK and wrap your code ([example here on GitHub](https://github.com/christopheranderson/azure-functions-app-insights-sample/blob/master/cs-http/run.csx)), but we'll do this automatically in the near future.

Comment: Looking forward to those improvements. What is the best page to monitor for news on that?

Comment: Updates page is the best place to find all new changes: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/

It is noisy. If you just wanna learn about Azure Functions, I tweet all the important stuff - [@crandycodes](https://twitter.com/crandycodes)

Comment: Hi Chris, I finally had a look at that AI sample you referenced, and see the "wrap your code" pattern for the Operation Context. Would this still be the code pattern that we'll use once AI is integrated into Functions?

Comment: Also am curious to understand in that referenced example why they had the first telemetry.TrackEvent() outside of the using()?

Comment: You can use this code pattern even with the new support to add your own custom metrics/events. We'll have trace support out of the box.

Comment: There wasn't a reason. Just showing you don't have to put it in the using context which links them all to 1 operation.

Comment: Working on improving the sample + more docs for the App Insights stuff so it's not just a random code snippet. :P